# Convert dtype('<U13309') to string in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, types, bert-language-model

I have a numpy array containing text data created by a groupby of pandas dataframe and further data preprocessing.
Now I want to fit my data into a model, but I get the following error message:

```
ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U13309'), dtype('<U13309')) -> dtype('<U13309')
```

I looked further into my array data and saw, that the array also was of dtype `dtype('<U13309')`.

I have never seen that before, I can only guess its some kind of binary data format, which shows me strings, but that are not well processable by python.

So two questions: How can I convert my `dtype('<U13309')` array to a string array and what is this dtype?

Thank you!

Comment: can't you use `str()`?

Comment: I fixed it now by converting my np.array() back to a list, still I dont know what that meant

Comment: That is a string - a very long unicode one.  You can't math on such an array